# How to copy files from the folder without the folder itself

Tags: bash, command-line, cp

I'm trying to copy files and subfolders from **A** folder without the **A** itself. For instance, **A** folder contains next:

```
| file1.txt   
| file2.txt    
| subfolder1
```

Executing next command gives me wrong result:

```
sudo cp -r /home/username/A/ /usr/lib/B/
```

The result is

```
/usr/lib/B/A/...copied files...
```

instead of..

```
/usr/lib/B/...copied files...
```

How can I reach the expected one without **origin-folder**

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**advanced cp**

```
cp -r /home/username/A/. /usr/lib/B/
```

This is especially great because it works no matter whether the target directory already exists.

**shell globbing**

If there are not too many objects in the directory then you can use shell globbing:

```
mkdir -p /usr/lib/B/
shopt -s dotglob
cp -r /home/username/A/* /usr/lib/B/
```

**rsync**

```
rsync -a /home/username/A/ /usr/lib/B/
```

The `/` at the end of the source path is important; works no matter whether the target directory already exists.

**find**

```
mkdir -p /usr/lib/B/
find /home/username/A/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec cp -r -t /usr/lib/B/ {} +
```

or if you don't need empty subdirectories:

```
find /home/username/A/ -mindepth 1 -type f -exec cp --parents -t /usr/lib/B/ {} +
```

(without `mkdir`)

Comment: The first one works just fine! Any ideas why **home/username/A/*** (with star-symbol) doesn't make sense? Variant with dot at the end helped me, thanks!

Comment: @pushandpop `A/*` does make sense but there are situations in which it doesn't work.

Comment: `shopt` is `bash` specific. With `zsh`, use `*(D)`. with `ksh93`, `FIGNORE='@(.|..)'`. `cp -t` is GNU specific. The `find` one will not work properly as it will copy both `A/` and its content (including subdirs) several times.

Comment: You also want `-maxdepth 1` (`-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` being GNU extensions now also supported by a few others. Portably `find .../. ! -name . -prune -exec ....`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I guess there is a typo somewhere. `find .../.` causes an error here.

Comment: `...` was an ellipsis for `/home/username/A`. It shouldn't give you a syntax error though, just a _file not found_ one (unless you have a directory called `...`).

Comment: is adding `.` after `/` mandatory ? seems to work without it

Comment: @Veverke It does work if you run the command only once (and know for sure that `B` doesn't exist). But run both commands twice and compare the results.

Comment: Use `cp -a /home/username/A/. /usr/lib/B/` (i.e., instead of `-r` use `-a`) to preserve symlinks and file attributes.

Answer (score 36):

If on a GNU system, from `man cp`:

```
   -T, --no-target-directory
          treat DEST as a normal file
```

This allows you to write `cp -rT /home/username/A/ /usr/lib/B/` to do exactly the right thing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, this is proper than shell globbing or using something else than `cp`. But that's true that `-T` won't work with a non-GNU `cp`.

Comment: Nice, but this answer (nor the man page) doesn't explain why treating DEST as normal file results in this wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Tell `cp` to copy the directory's contents and not the directory itself:

```
sudo cp -r /home/username/A/* /usr/lib/B/
```

Comment: Thanks! But it says: **/usr/lib/B/** is not a directory

Comment: You will need to `shopt -s dotglob` for this to work if there are any dotfiles in `/home/username/A/`.

Comment: @pushandpop well, yes. That's the target you had in your question so I assumed it was a directory. You need to create the target before attempting to copy files into it.

Comment: is adding `*` after the `/` is mandatory ? seems to work without it

Comment: @Veverke without it, you copy the directory. With it, you copy only what is inside the directory.

Comment: @that's why I asked, I always thought the same - my script had /*, but using only / seems to copy the files inside it (and adding it to a cp will create the dir as well). I am a beginner in linux but this is what I see when looking at the results running the command with both syntaxes.

Comment: @Veverke please post a new question if you need more details and show us the exact commands you used. That said, if you run `cp -r foo/* bar` one of two things will happen: if `bar` does not exist, or if it exists but is not a directory, you will get an error message. If it does exist and is a directory, then all non-hidden files/dirs from `foo` will be copied into `bar`. If you run `cp -r foo/ bar`, then if `bar` exists and is a directory, that will copy the directory `foo` and place it as a subdirectory of `bar`. If `bar` does not exist or is not a directory, you will get an error.