# Create a folder for each file in a folder without the folder itself

Tags: command-line, find, directory, mkdir

```
        | folderA1 | fileA11, fileA12, ...
folderA | folderA2 | fileA21, fileA22...
        |  ...     | ...
```

I want to make a copy of it represented as:

```
        | folderA1 | folderA11, folderA12, ...
folderB | folderA2 | folderA21, folderA22, ...
        | ...      |  ...
```

The original folderA (and it's structure) remains as it is (unchanged).

I'm trying to create a **folder** in (folder) B for each file in a (folder) A without the folder itself. I also would like to maintain the directory structure of the original folder (A).

Using [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180985/how-to-copy-files-from-the-folder-without-the-folder-itself) I'm able to achieve the generation of the above but it contains the folder A itself.

```
find source/. -type d -exec mkdir -p dest/{} \; \
   -o -type f -exec mkdir -p dest/{} \;
```

Looks like:

```
         |         | folderA1 | folderA11, folderA12, ...
 folderB | folderA | folderA2 | folderA21, folderA22, ...
         |         | ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `cd` into `folderA` and run the command from there:

```
cd folderA
find . -type d -o -type f -exec bash -c '
  for path; do mkdir -p "/path/to/folderB/${path/file/folder}"; done
' bash {} +
```

The parameter expansion `${path/file/folder}` renames the each `fileXY` to `folderXY`.

If every folder contains files, you can remove the `-type d -o`.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly.