# Where can I find the official document on advanced cp command?

Tags: cp, man

I want to copy all contents in folder A(but not include A itself) to another folder B recursively, and overwrite any existing files or folders with the same name.

Originally I plan to use the following command:

```
cp -f -r /home/alan/A/* /home/alan/B/
```

However, after searching online, I find all others recommend the following format:

```
cp -f -r /home/alan/A/. /home/alan/B/
```

such as:

[How can I copy the contents of a folder to another folder in a different directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86822/how-can-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-folder-to-another-folder-in-a-different-directo)
[How to copy files from the folder without the folder itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180985/how-to-copy-files-from-the-folder-without-the-folder-itself)

The strange thing is that I cannot find any **official** document on this advanced `cp` command. I tried to use:

```
man cp
info coreutils 'cp invocation'
cp --help
```

But none of them indicate such usage. How can I find the official document on advanced cp command and usage?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cp behaves weirdly when . (dot) or .. (dot dot) are the source directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409225/cp-behaves-weirdly-when-dot-or-dot-dot-are-the-source-directory) ... It's not exactly undocumented, it's just not explicitly documented.

Comment: @muru, Thank you very much. It is hard to understand but I finally understand. Thank you very much.